# Using Selenium in Python to click on HTML Tag with Java does not work

Tags: python, selenium

A web page has page numbers which can be clicked to advance to the next page.
The page numbers are in an  tag with href to a javascript call.

After this...

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

xpath = 'appropriate_xpath_string'

wait_presence = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
)
wait_clickable = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
)
```

And calculating scroll_y = distance needed to make element visible...

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,', scroll_y, ')')
```

I've tried the following:

`driver_find_element_by_xpath('xpath').click()`

`driver_find_element_by_xpath('xpath').send_keys('\ue007')` (Sending the Enter key.)

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)` (The JavaScript trick.)

ActionChains clicking

Problematic Element:

```
<a href="javascript:__doThis('nl00$CPH1$dOR$n16$nl01','')">2</a>
```

__doThis() function essentially does a form .submit() with some parameters.

Edit:
After sending the click event Developer Tools shows an error:

```
VM1560:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: __doThis is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

After scanning through the HTML/js I noticed that the __doThis function is not defined in ChromeDriver. When I load the page in Edge or Chrome the  tag with __doThis function is present. So why is the javascript function not loading in ChromeDriver?

EDIT 2:
I loaded chromedriver.exe without configuring special options and this solved the problem. Now I need to figure out what option was breaking the page's javascript function.

EDIT 3:
It seems this section of code breaks the in-page javascript:

```
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
        "source": """
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
          get: () => undefined
        })
      """
    })
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": {"User-Agent": "browser1"}})
```

I need to do some research to understand why.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the URL and button you're clicking?

Comment: Updated problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "2"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I did not explicitly state that I already have all those imports and implemented the wait. I used the python terminal to try many options after the page loaded and have been unable to get it to respond.

Comment: i hope you already verified your element is not within iframe, also what error you are facing , is it possible for you to provide url ?

Comment: unfortunately this is on a corporate intranet and inaccessible to the general public. There is no <iframe/>

Answer (score 0):

Try following code which will scrolled to element view using `location_once_scrolled_into_view`

```
wait_presence = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
wait_presence.location_once_scrolled_into_view
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", wait_presence)
```

---

OR javascripts executor to scroll.

```
wait_presence = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", wait_presence)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", wait_presence)
```

Comment: The issue is not visibility. The issue is that the element does not respond to any form of input. I can find the element.

`print(type(element))`

Result: <class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>